# getItemViewType not called RecyclerView

Tags: android

when doing a recycleview does not send the getitemviewtype, some example to compare, never enters the getitemviewtype

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    Object item = list.get(position);
    Log.e(TAG, "getItemViewType: " +item);
    if (item instanceof NativeAppInstallAdView){
        Log.e("TYPODE", "instalacion");
        return NATIVE_APP_INSTALL_AD_VIEW_TYPE;
    }
    else if(item instanceof NativeContentAd){
        Log.e("TYPODE", "anuncio");
        return NATIVE_CONTENT_AD_VIEW_TYPE;
    }else {
        Log.e("TYPODE", "normal");
        return NOTIFICATION_VIEW_TYPE;
    }
}
```

Comment: i don't thing most audience understand spanish. However you can visit https://es.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: I understand Spanish, but you should make this question in es.stackoverflow.com as Killer already pointed out.

Comment: Gracias esto me funciono

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried calling the `getItemViewType()` method from the `onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position)` method?

```
//Your current method
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    Object item = list.get(position);
    Log.e(TAG, "getItemViewType: " +item);
    if (item instanceof NativeAppInstallAdView){
        Log.e("TYPODE", "instalacion");
        return NATIVE_APP_INSTALL_AD_VIEW_TYPE;
    }
    else if(item instanceof NativeContentAd){
        Log.e("TYPODE", "anuncio");
        return NATIVE_CONTENT_AD_VIEW_TYPE;
    }else {
        Log.e("TYPODE", "normal");
        return NOTIFICATION_VIEW_TYPE;
    }
}

//Call getItemViewType() method from here
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    switch (holder.getItemViewType()) {
        case NATIVE_APP_INSTALL_AD_VIEW_TYPE:
            ViewHolderApp viewHolderApp = (ViewHolderApp)holder;
            ...
            break;

        case NATIVE_CONTENT_AD_VIEW_TYPE:
            ViewHolderContent viewHolderContent = (ViewHolderContent)holder;
            ...
            break;
        case NOTIFICATION_VIEW_TYPE:
            ViewHolderView viewHolderView = (ViewHolderView)holder;                
            ...
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Gracias esto me funciono